# Should self be captured as strong in a presentViewController completion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

When writing the handler closure of a `presentViewController` `completion` , should the reference to self be strong (the default), weak, or unwowned?

```
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:^{
                [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            }];
```

Note that I don't store the completion block in self but what happens if `presentViewController`  `completion` block is stored as property in Apple implementation ?

Comment: It only means that the view controller can't be deallocated until the block is freed.  I am not sure what harm there would be if the view controller happened to be deallocated during the animation, but it doesn't hurt to prevent it.

Comment: It's true that completion block will keep a strong reference to self. But in this case you don't need to worry because that completion handler is a part of UIViewController and UIViewController is responsible for releasing the block. And I'm pretty sure Apple has taken care of that.